# Execute function until certain condition holds

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I want to repeatedly apply some function to some state until a condition holds true.

Function f takes a state, modifies it and returns it. Apply f again to the returned state and so on.

I think this would work.

```
(first (filter pred (iterate f x)))
```

But it's a bit ugly. Plus memory consumption is not ideal since iterator would be forced to evaluate and keep intermediate states until the state on which pred holds true is returned, at which point intermediate states should be garbage collected.

I know you can write a simple recursive function:

```
(loop [f x p] (if (p x) x (recur f (f x) p))
```

But I'm looking for a core library function (or some combination of functions) that does the same thing with the same memory efficiency.

Answer (score 7):

What you really want is [take-while](http://clojure.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/take-while):

```
take-while
function

Usage: (take-while pred coll)
Returns a lazy sequence of successive items from coll while
(pred item) returns true. pred must be free of side-effects.
```

EDIT

A way to use higher order functions to achieve the result you want might be to wrap your function into something to be consumed by `trampoline`, namely a function that will either return the final result or another function which will execute the next step. Here's the code:

```
(defn iterable [f]            ; wraps your function
  (fn step [pred x]           ; returns a new function which will accept the predicate
    (let [y (f x)]            ; calculate the current step result
      (if (pred y)            ; recursion stop condition
        (fn [] (step pred y)) ; then: return a new fn for trampoline, operates on y
        y))))                 ; else: return a value to exit the trampoline
```

The iterative execution would go as follows:

```
(trampoline (iterable dec) pos? 10)
```

Answer (score 4):

Not sure what you mean by `iterator` - you're using it as if it were `iterate`, and I just want to be sure that's what you mean. At any rate, your solution looks fine to me and not at all ugly. And memory is not an issue either: `iterate` is free to throw away intermediate results whenever it's convenient because you aren't keeping any references to them, just calling `filter` on it in a "streaming" way.

Comment: Yes, I meant iterate. That was a typo. But this makes sense. I ran this so that pred always returned true and the I don't get a out of memory exception.

Answer (score 4):

I think you should just make your loop a simple recursive function:

```
(defn do-until [f x p]
  (if (p x) x (recur f (f x) p)))

(do-until inc 0 #(> % 10)) ; => 11
```

Comment: Yes, of course, this is a good solution. But it's good to practice the use of higher order functions in the core library to abstract away recursion. By the way, I would call this apply-until. It would be nice to have something like this in the core library.

Answer (score 3):

How about drop-while

```
(first (drop-while (comp not pred) (iterate f x))
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a core function that does this exactly and efficiently. Hence I would do this with loop/recur as follows:

```
(loop [x initial-value]
  (if (pred x) x (recur (f x))))
```

Loop/recur is very efficient since it requires no additional storage and is implemented as a simple loop in the JVM.

If you're going to do this a lot, then you can always encapsulate the pattern in a macro.

Comment: I agree with your answer, except it doesn't need to be a macro?  A simple recursive function would work just as well?

Comment: @dbryne sure - you can make it a function as well if you like. though in this case I think I'd prefer a macro - you'd get slightly better runtime efficiency, and I tend to prefer macros for anything that feels like a "control structure".

Comment: I agree that this is the most efficient solution. And that's what I would have done if this weren't just for practice. An advantage is that it's easy to reason about about performance. If this were something I was going to use a lot, I'd use a function. I am thinking that this type of function could be inlined by the JVM, so I am not sure why you'd want to use a macro.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the `while` macro.

http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/while

> Usage: (while test & body)
>   Repeatedly executes body while test expression is true. Presumes
>   some side-effect will cause test to become false/nil. Returns nil

In a slightly different use case the `for` macro supports :when and :while options too.

http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/for

> Usage: (for seq-exprs body-expr)
>   List comprehension. Takes a vector of one or more
>   binding-form/collection-expr pairs, each followed by zero or more
>   modifiers, and yields a lazy sequence of evaluations of expr.
>   Collections are iterated in a nested fashion, rightmost fastest,
>   and nested coll-exprs can refer to bindings created in prior
>   binding-forms.  Supported modifiers are: :let [binding-form expr ...],
>   :while test, :when test.
>
> (take 100 (for [x (range 100000000) y (range 1000000) :while (< y x)] [x y]))

Comment: Not sure about while since it requires a side effect. Didn't think of this, but for would work, but you'd still use iterate (first (for [z (iterate f x) :while (pred z))

Comment: Have a look at the source for `while` and you will see it is very like what you would code by hand. Remember that data is immutable in clojure so the "a side effect" in this case could simply be a update to the state of var x.